# AJAX Panel not working on initial global RouteTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, routes

**OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium
**Compiler:** Visual Studio 2012
**Language:** ASP.net C# 4
**Additional Notes:** Using a `Master` page with a script manager on. The `Content` pages have the `AJAX` panels.

In my `Global.asax`, I have a routing table that routes these addresses:

```
//Site
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx");   
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}/{resource}", "~/{address}/{resource}.aspx");
```

This allows me to cut out the .aspx part of the page, and makes the URL look more pleasing.

When I run my site for the first time (After I restart the compiling PC), all the `AJAX` panels stop working. Any auto complete extender, button, text box etc loose their `AJAX` abilities.

I realised this was the problem, so I edited out the above code. As expected, the site restored itself to fix the `AJAX` issue.

But, after the previous solution, I unedited the first bit of code, only to find that all my `AJAX` panels still work. So, I literally have to comment out the code, reload the site, then uncomment the code for the pages to start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a route that manages the resource extensions.

The following code fixed my problem:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //Make sure to add this BEFORE any other routes.
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //Site
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}", "~/{address}.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{address}/{resource}", "~/{address}/{resource}.aspx");
}
```

Thanks to [This post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/ajax/system-web-routing-and-asp-net-ajax-client-side-framework-failed-to-load.aspx).